# Error: package ‘StanHeaders’ 2.18.1 was found, but > 2.18.1 is required by ‘rstan’

Tags: r, version

I am writing [an R package](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap) that depends on Stan and Rstan. I run the installation on an Azure machine `Standard_D64_v3` and install `r-base` and `r-cran-stan` with `sudo apt-get` and `rstan` and `Rcpp` with `R`'s `install.packages()`(among others, see [shell setup script](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/blob/59-paper-code/azure/setup.sh) and [R setup script](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/blob/59-paper-code/azure/setup.R)).

This process worked OK last month. Today I was able to install the package (as evidenced by the welcome message) and then have a runtime error from incompatible versions.

```
...
* DONE (PosteriorBootstrap)
Reloading attached PosteriorBootstrap
Welcome to PosteriorBootstrap, a parallel approach for adaptive non-parametric learning
Error: package ‘StanHeaders’ 2.18.1 was found, but > 2.18.1 is required by ‘rstan’
In addition: Warning message:
version 2.18.1.10 of ‘StanHeaders’ masked by 2.18.1 in /usr/lib/R/site-library 
Execution halted
```

I do not have `StanHeaders` anywhere in my code so I suspect the problem is between different packages. How can I solve this problem with versions?

Comment: Try reinstalling `StanHeaders` with `install.packages("StanHeaders")`.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nicola wrote in the comments, the fix is to reinstall `StanHeaders` with:

```r
install.packages("StanHeaders")
```

The previous code may have stopped working because of a new version of R, but I could not determine the cause.